# Passing service from child component to parent component

Tags: angular, typescript, frontend, web-frontend

So I have a Base Component (ListComponent) and a ParentComponent (Businesses2ListComponent). The idea is that we have Lists with multiple tables/types which all derive from the ListComponent. Therefore we have to pass the correct service.

In this example I want to pass the BusinessService (which extends BaseService) to the BaseComponent.

Here's the ListComponent:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-list',
  templateUrl: './list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./list.component.scss']
})
export class ListComponent<S extends BaseService<T, L>, T, L> implements OnInit {

  constructor(private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef,
              private domElement: ElementRef,
              private ngForage: NgForage,
              private route: ActivatedRoute,
              private router: Router,
              private injector: Injector,
              private dataService: S) {
  }
  
}
```

And this is my Business2ListComponent:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-businesses2-list',
  templateUrl: './businesses2-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./businesses2-list.component.scss']
})
export class Businesses2ListComponent extends ListComponent<BusinessService, Business, BusinessList> implements OnInit {

  constructor(viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef,
              domElement: ElementRef,
              ngForage: NgForage,
              dataService: BusinessService,
              route: ActivatedRoute,
              router: Router,
              injector: Injector) {
    super(viewContainerRef, domElement, ngForage, route, router, injector, dataService);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Now this is the error I get when trying to run this:
[image: Screenshot]
[image: Screenshot 2]

I think it's the last argument that screws up, but what can I do else?

Answer (score 0):

When Angular shows the question mark it cannot find the object that you're trying to inject, this could be a number of reasons but a good starting place is your module file. Have you added your instantiated BusinessService to your module providers?

Comment: I added the BusinessService to the AppModule (it was in BusinessesModule before) but it didn't change anything. I've also added errors I have in the console to the original post.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that on your constructor where : `private dataService: S`.

2 options: You can change your constructor to take in like this:

`private dataService: new () => S`

You may get TSLint error on your `BusinessListComponent` constructor when you call your `super()`, but it works.

Alternatively my prefer approached in your case using OOP, since I don't see any reason to pass in `BusinessService` on your `ListComponent<BusinessService, Business, BusinessList>`. Here's a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fqym1g) showing this method.

Where your `BusinessListComponent`

```
export class BusinessListComponent extends ListComponent<Business, BusinessList> implements OnInit {

  constructor(//...your args, private businessService: BusinessService) { 
    super(// ... your args, businessService);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

Your `ListComponent` becomes like this:

```
export class ListComponent<T, L> implements OnInit {
  constructor(private dataService: BaseService<T, L>) { 
  }
  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

And where your `BusinessService`

```
export class BusinessService extends BaseService<Business, BusinessList> {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: The last approach isn't possible like this, because the BusinessService sets an endpoint and a serializer for the BaseService. I tried it and have an error in the request that is sent to the server (endpoint is undefined). The first one doesn't work either. I have the same errors in the console as before.

Comment: Maybe you can make a simple stackblitz based on your code for this issue? Though not sure how your original code for `ListComponent<S extends BaseService<T, L>, T, L>` is any different since its a type check for `S` to extend `BaseService` therefore you would end up the same error as my 2nd approach.

Comment: Here it is: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-t542ym - I removed everything T & L related in the ListComponent to keep it simple.

Comment: @YassineZeriouh, there was alot of errors in stackblitz couldnt get it to compile so here's a fork of yours with barebone to get the `endpoint` but with my implementation on the second approach. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h9pxm3 , if you look at the console you can see the endpoint, maybe I'm doing something differently on how you are calling your services? I'm not sure.